# Hilbert space and eigenvalues for Hamiltonian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics

The Hilbert-space of this system in
the Schrödinger representation is again given by $L_2(-1,1)$. In this Hilbert space, we
consider the two functions $g_0(x):=(1+i)\exp(i \pi x)$ and $g_1(x):=\exp(i 2 \pi x)$.

I have shown that $g_0$ and $g_1$ are orthogonal in $L_2([-1,1])$ and I have found that the orthonormal states are $\phi_0=\frac{g_0(x)}{2}$ and $\phi_1=\frac{g_1(x)}{\sqrt{2}}$.
Now I have to show that the functions $\phi_0$ and $\phi_1$ are eigenvectors/eigenfunctions for $H=-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\partial^2_x-C$ for $C \in \mathbb{R},$ and I should determine the corresponding eigenvalues. Can anyone help me with an argument. What will the $H$ matrix be? Is C just a constant we can ignore?

Comment: I think you mean that the $\phi_s$ are eigenfunctions? But why not just work out $H\phi_0$ and $H\phi_1$?

Comment: Yeah it must be eigenfunctions/eigenvectors $\phi_s$. What do you mean by work out $H\phi_0$ and $H\phi_1$?

Comment: It seems to me easy to crunch out $H\phi_1$ and get $H\phi_1=\lambda\phi_1$ with $\lambda=\frac{4\pi^2 h}{m}-C$.

Comment: Aha smart trick

Comment: It's not a trick, it's the definition of the terms "eigenfunction" and "eigenvalue".

Comment: Nice, I have forgot that. But what will the corresponding eigenvalues then be?

Comment: But I've told you that for $\phi_1$: $\lambda$ is by definition the ev.